# Sharing one PS4 subscription account linked to my gmail account for both sons

Tags: ps4

I've a PS4 membership account linked to my email address.  My two sons tell me this means they have to share the account and all their Fifa games are linked to each others; this is causing endless strife in the house!  Is there any way I can separate 'the account' so that they can each have theie own Fifa games and they're not linked to each other.  I'm not at all tech savvy, so would really appreciate some simple, clear, plain english advice:-).
L

Answer (score 1):

You need to create subaccounts for each of your sons.  You can do this by going to Settings->Parental Controls->Family Management->Add Family Member.

Each son will then be able to log in separately and will have their own save games.  If you have PS+, they will get the PS+ benefits, though you will need to download any games owned under your account when logged in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This will not do. Save files are for one account, and **cannot** be split.
You will have to make a new account, and give it *PS Plus* to allow both to play FIFA (assuming the original is still being paid for) without any save files screwups.